# UIButton as back button, without addSubView

Tags: iphone, button, uibutton, back-button

i have two views
1st one is displaying list (uitableview used), user will select one row from list and go to 2nd view
in 2nd view i am colleting data from server and displaying data on label or text field

now in second view I hide my back button(navigation bar) and add new UIbutton as Disconnect(using interface builder)

so when user press on this Disconnect button he should move back to 1st view.

but without [self.view addSubView:1stview.view]; --- because this one is not working as what i want.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@pooja add this code in your 2nd View and you please connect this IBAction to you disconnect button

```
    (IBAction) moveToFist {
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: hey thank u sooo much, i was searching this more than 2 hours..u saved my more time thanks once again

Comment: +1 make connection from IB with touch up inside event if you use IB.

Answer (score 1):

On that disconnect button's IBaction method

write

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```